# Can't download file if local dir has other files by SI ftp inBound adaptor

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

The SI config is as shown below, when there are files or sub-dir under local directory, the remote file can't be downloaded, if the local directory is empty, it works fine, any advice?

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>                
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>                
    <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>                
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound" 
                  channel="ftpChannel" 
                  session-factory="ftpClientFactory" 
                  charset="UTF-8"
                  filename-pattern="*.txt" 
                  auto-create-local-directory="true" 
                  delete-remote-files="false" 
                  remote-directory="/export/home/data"
                  remote-file-separator="/"
                  local-directory="resources/smooks/files">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be downloaded" ? Are you getting exceptions? If a file already exists locally, it will be re-fetched, but you won't get a message on `ftpChannel` because the default `local-filter` is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Prior to 3.0, there was no way to override this behavior; `local-filter` was introduced in 3.0. http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#3.0-(s)ftp-changes

Comment: Thanks, Gary. What I mean that according to SI config, I want to download .txt file, say aaa.txt, but if there is file (e.g. bbb.ear) on my local dir, the remote file aaa.txt can't be downloaded, even for the first time.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me; some other existing file will make no difference to the operation of the adapter. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to see what's happening.

Comment: Hi Gary, I just run your ftp example, get the same problem.

Comment: Can you explain EXACTLY what you tried? I just ran a test fetching to a directory that already has files and subdirectories and all worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, Gay. If your test is OK, it is my system issue.